# Android - API Rest communication error on sending JSON data

Tags: android, rest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect with my API Rest (it works perfect on Postman) but all time I am getting 400 response codes. I have to say that I am a newbie in Android.

This is my code

```
try {
    URL apiServerUrl = new URL(BASE_URL+AUTHORIZE_ROUTE);
    HttpURLConnection apiConnection = (HttpURLConnection) apiServerUrl.openConnection();
    apiConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Adagal Presence Terminal");
    //apiConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    apiConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    apiConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    apiConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    apiConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    apiConnection.setUseCaches( false );
    apiConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Codificamos los parámetros
    String str =  "{\"username\": \""+selectedUser+"\",\"password\":\""+selectedUser+"\", \"grant_type\": \"password\",\"client_id\":\""+CLIENT_ID+"\",\"client_secret\":\""+CLIENT_SECRET+"\"}";
    byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    OutputStream os = apiConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write( outputInBytes );

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    InputStream inputStream;

    int status = apiConnection.getResponseCode();

    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        inputStream = apiConnection.getErrorStream();
    else
        inputStream = apiConnection.getInputStream();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        sb.append((char)c);
    String response = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(response);

} catch (IOException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

I connect to the URL, pass the Json data and get an Exception (Response code 400).

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

I hope you mean this as the StackTrace:

```
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? E/Zygote: v2
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10172
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0025
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=net.adagal.adagalpresence 
03-01 19:01:45.744 28414-28414/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-01 19:01:45.794 28414-28414/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
03-01 19:01:45.794 28414-28414/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
03-01 19:01:45.854 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/net.adagal.adagalpresence-2/lib/arm
03-01 19:01:45.864 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is net.adagal.adagalpresence, real application class is net.adagal.adagalpresence.presenceApplication.
03-01 19:01:45.874 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error
03-01 19:01:47.084 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/net.adagal.adagalpresence-2/lib/arm
03-01 19:01:47.354 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-01 19:01:47.694 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-01 19:01:47.694 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-01 19:01:47.764 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
03-01 19:01:47.764 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e21224 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
03-01 19:01:47.764 28414-28656/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-01 19:01:47.844 28414-28656/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (Ia10634f51b)
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                       Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
                                                                       Local Branch: 
                                                                       Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
                                                                       Local Patches: NONE
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
03-01 19:01:47.844 28414-28656/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-01 19:01:47.884 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
03-01 19:01:47.904 28414-28656/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : net.adagal.adagalpresence
03-01 19:01:47.984 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
03-01 19:01:48.064 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@53dab7 time:18291774
03-01 19:01:48.064 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@53dab7 time:18291774
03-01 19:01:48.304 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 404) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 404) or=1
03-01 19:01:48.334 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
03-01 19:01:50.424 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-01 19:01:50.484 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-01 19:01:53.334 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-01 19:01:53.434 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-01 19:01:53.624 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 333) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 333) or=1
03-01 19:01:53.644 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
03-01 19:01:55.234 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-01 19:01:55.294 28414-28414/net.adagal.adagalpresence D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-01 19:01:55.324 28414-29165/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-01 19:01:55.324 28414-29165/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-01 19:01:55.444 28414-29165/net.adagal.adagalpresence I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.3.67:8000/authorize
```

**EDIT (JSONObject params)**
I changed code portion of the hande made json for the JSON object with the link you passed me. But still same result.

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
try {
    params.put("username", selectedUser);
    params.put("password", selectedPass);
    params.put("grant_type", "password");
    params.put("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
    params.put("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
} catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.println("JSON Exception: "+e.toString());
}
OutputStreamWriter paramWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(apiConnection.getOutputStream());
paramWriter.write(params.toString());
```

Comment: Post the full StackTrace if possible. Error code 400 means bad request; the request you sent to the server, is incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

Comment: switch to retrofit2.

Comment: Added the result, I hope thats the StackTrace you mean. And Caspain I dont understand what are you saying, sorry.

Comment: May be your json is malformed, please use JSONObject https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html and compose json string and sent it again to server.

Comment: agree with @sector11 - to emphasize a bit more **NEVER COMPOSE JSON STRINGS BY HAND**, always use available libraries.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I post my edited code.